# Binding a bool to multiple result in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, reactive-cocoa

I am doing some experiments on ReactiveCocoa in both Objective-C language and Swift. However, I can not find a way to implement the same functionality with Swift

Here is the Objective-C version:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        RAC(self, isLoginButtonEnabled) = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACObserve(self, username), RACObserve(self, password)] reduce:^(NSString *newUsername, NSString *newPassword) {

            return @(newUsername.length && newPassword.length);
        }];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I always got error when I do the same thing with Swift, BTW you need to import [Swift-RAC-Macros](https://github.com/ashfurrow/Swift-RAC-Macros) in order to get `RAC` and `RACOBserve` in Swift:

```
override init() {
    super.init()


    RAC(self, "isLoginButtonEnabled", false) <~ RACSignal.combineLatest([RACObserve(self, "username"), RACObserve(self, "password")], reduce: {(newUsername: String?, newPassword: String?) -> AnyObject? in

        return false;
    })
}
```

For this I always get error: 
`(RAC, _) is not convertible to 'RACSignal'`. Can anyone give me how to do that?

Comment: Note that what you're trying to do looks like it introduces a retain cycle.

Comment: which two? Can you explain a little more? I appreciate it.

Comment: my block does not retain `self`. Where do I have retain cycle? @erikprice

Comment: Blocks are not the only things that can retain `self`. You create two signals which, when subscribed to, do retain `self` – namely, the `username` and `password` observers. You then combine these two signals into a `combineWithLatest`, which retains those two signals for as long as it is subscribed to, and then you bind this signal to the `isLoginButtonEnabled` property on `self`, which implicitly retains that signal. Thus, `self` retains a signal that retains two signals that retain `self`. You'll need to explicitly dispose of the signals to break the retain cycle.

Comment: Sounds awesome. You have any clue of this question? @erikprice

Comment: BTW, should I just `weakify` the `self` when add observer? Or you can actually edit my post.

Comment: `weakify` is only useful to alias `self` to a weak reference for use within a block. Since a block isn't involved in the retain cycle you're faced with, it's not helpful to you. You need to capture the disposable returned from your signal subscriptions, and explicitly (manually) `dispose()` it when you no longer need to take action due to changes to `username` and `password`.

Comment: Thanks for advance. Do you think any ideas about my question.

Comment: @erikprice is that accurate? I didn't think RACObserve needed to be explicitly disposed of, based on this documentation in NSObject+RACPropertySubscribing.h:

/// In either case, the observation continues until `TARGET` _or self_ is
/// deallocated.

but I'm likely misunderstanding something?

Comment: @powerj1984 In this usage of `RACObserve()`, `TARGET` and `self` are the same object, and that object will not be deallocated until the retain cycle is broken.